# How do I copy and paste essays and informations to put onto my HTML page?

Tags: html

Something like this to actually appear on my page.

DECEMBER 1
World AIDS Day
National Pie Day
National Eat a Red Apple Day
Bifocals at the Monitor Liberation Day
Day With(out) Art Day
Rosa Parks Day

DECEMBER 2
International Day for the Abolition of Slavery
National Fritters Day
National Mutt Day
Special Education Day #SpecialEducationDay
Rockefeller Center Tree Lighting – Changes Annually
Faux Fur Friday – First Friday in December

DECEMBER 3
International Day of Persons with Disabilities
Roof Over Your Head Day #RoofOverYourHeadDay
National Rhubarb Vodka Day – First Saturday in December
Skywarn Recognition Day – First Saturday in December

DECEMBER 4
National Cookie Day
National Dice Day

DECEMBER 5
World Soil Day
International Volunteer Day for Economic and Social Development
National Sacher Torte Day
AFL-CIO Day
Bathtub Party Day
International Ninja Day
Repeal Day #RepealDay

DECEMBER 6
National Pawnbrokers Day
National Microwave Oven Day
National Gazpacho Day
St. Nicholas Day
Miners’ Day

DECEMBER 7
International Civil Aviation Day
National Pearl Harbor Remembrance Day
National Cotton Candy Day

DECEMBER 8
National Brownie Day
Pretend to Be a Time Traveler Day #PretendToBeATimeTravelerDay

DECEMBER 9
International Anti-Corruption Day
National Pastry Day
Weary Willie Day

DECEMBER 10
Dewey Decimal System Day
Human Rights Day
Nobel Prize Day
National Wreaths Across America Day – Second Saturday in December

DECEMBER 11
International Mountain Day
National Noodle Ring Day
UNICEF Birthday

DECEMBER 12
@MavenTheCorgi’s Birthday
National Ambrosia Day
National Ding-a-Ling Day
Gingerbread House Day
Poinsettia Day

DECEMBER 13
National Cocoa Day
National Violin Day
National Day Of The Horse (Senate Res. 452)
Pick a Pathologist Pal Day

Instead of something like this.

DECEMBER 1 World AIDS Day National Pie Day National Eat a Red Apple Day Bifocals at the Monitor Liberation Day Day With(out) Art Day Rosa Parks Day
DECEMBER 2 International Day for the Abolition of Slavery National Fritters Day National Mutt Day Special Education Day #SpecialEducationDay Rockefeller Center Tree Lighting â€“ Changes Annually Faux Fur Friday â€“ First Friday in December DECEMBER 3

Much help would be appreciated thanks!!

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is an absolute **fundamental** of HTML. You should probably do a bit of research on how HTML is written before asking for help. You may find this useful: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp

Answer (score -1):

After further searching I think I have the solution you need.

Use the "pre" tag and you will get the result you want.

Example:

```
<pre>
This will be presented in the browser

just like I write it here.
</pre>
```

You can also see this example: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_pre

I hope this answer is good enough.

Comment: But the problem is that I have an endless amount of dates, are there any other faster way to organize them? Or maybe just copy that text and throw it in without it being a mess?

Comment: Alon you dont use <br> for that

Comment: Well as I said this is not the best thing to do... You can put a <p> or <div> around each paragraph and that will do the same. But just to make sure. do you just want to put this text in an html and that there will be spaces between the paragraphs in the outcome?